# x.split Giving IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, list, split

My code looks like this

```
   df2['min_salary'] = min_hr.apply(lambda x: int(x.split('-')[0]))
   df2['max_salary'] = min_hr.apply(lambda x: int(x.split('-')[1]))
```

the data its using is a Salary column that looks like this     80 - 100
The min salary works fine, but the max salary keeps on coming up with the error. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: That strongly suggests that at least one of your rows does not actually look like "80 - 100", but probably has just "100".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tim points out, you likely have data which doesn't follow the exact format you're trying to split the strings on. You could try this approach, which adds `NaN` to any columns which didn't produce two values from splitting:

```py
df2[["min_salary", "max_salary"]] = min_hr.str.split("-").apply(pd.Series)
```

Here's an example output after using that code on the `"A"` column of this dataframe (and naming the two new columns `"Ax"` and `"Ay"`:

```py
       A  Ax   Ay
0  10-20  10   20
1  30-40  30   40
2     70  70  NaN
```

Note that if you want single salary values to fill into the `"max_salary"` column, you'll need to use a slightly different approach:

```py
df2[["min_salary", "max_salary"]] = min_hr.split("-").apply(lambda x: [np.nan]*(len(x) < 2) + x).to_list()
```

Which puts `70` in the `Ay` column:

```py
       A   Ax  Ay
0  10-20   10  20
1  30-40   30  40
2     70  NaN  70
```

Another approach (and possibly ideal in this particular case) would be to fill `NaN` laterally:

```py
df2[["min_salary", "max_salary"]] = min_hr.str.split("-").apply(pd.Series).ffill(axis=1)
```

```py
       A  Ax  Ay
0  10-20  10  20
1  30-40  30  40
2     70  70  70
```

Note that none of these solutions convert your data to numeric types.

Comment: Tim is correct! There is one piece of data that is just "100" I made the correction. Thanks a bunch. Been stuck on this for 20 minutes

Comment: Cool, well the code I've added achieves your result in a much cleaner way, and adds `NaN` for missing data. Consider using this code anyway!

Comment: @Jordan see my updated solution, as I think it might be better for your use-case. It fills `NaN` laterally, so in the case of your column with just `100` for salary, it would produce a `min_salary` and `max_salary` both with a value of 100.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. This should handle if 'x' doesn't have - in it

```
df2['max_salary'] = min_hr.apply(lambda x: int(x.split('-')[1] if len(x.split('-'))>1 else x.split('-')[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def min_max_value(sal_string):
    fields = x.split('-')
    if len(fields)>1:
        if fields[0].strip().isdigit():
            min_field = int(fields[0].strip())
        else:
            min_field = None
        if fields[1].strip().isdigit():
            max_field = int(fields[0].strip())
        else:
            max_field = None
    else:
        if fields[0].strip().isdigit():
            min_field = int(fields[0].strip())
        else:
            min_field, max_field = None, None
    return min_field, max_field
df2[['min_salary','max_salary']] = min_hr.apply(min_max_value, result_type="expand")
```

You can try something like this.